# Magento Transactional Email editing not working

Tags: magento, transactional

I have a transactional email template based on file (`app/locale/et_EE/template/email/sales`) under `order_new.html` name. I wanted to change some information, edited it in Notepad, saved, overwrote it. But new emails still have old information. How can I solve this problem?

Maybe it is because of file permissions attribute? The old one had 755, new one 644.

**Update:** Thank you, guys, for sharing thoughts and ideas! The problem was that I made changes in a wrong FTP server :D Sorry!

Comment: Your theory about the file permissions has merit. Have you tried changing them with `chmod`? Or checked the owner/changed the owner with `chown`?

Comment: Are you testing as a guest user?  Be sure to also edit the `order_new_guest.html` template.

Comment: @PatrickM tried `chmod` (changed from 644 to 755), same result, unfortunately.

Comment: @Axel testing as a registered user (guest users not allowed to make orders).

Answer (score 0):

Here are some debugging points that may help you solve your issue.

1. Make sure the locale is correct in **System > Configuration > General > Locale Options**.  The **Locale** should be set to `Estonian (Estonia)` for the store you are using to send the emails.
2. To discover what template is being used, you can turn on [Template Path Hints](http://www.westwideweb.com/wp/2009/08/04/magento-how-to-turn-on-template-path-hints-and-inline-translation/).

   First go to your **System > Configuration > Developer** section.

   Then  at the top left of the page, set the **Current Configuration Scope** to your website (2nd option in the dropdown list).

   The option **Template Path Hints** will now appear under the **Debug** section.  Set it to `Yes` and hit Save Config.

   Flush your Magento caches, and generate a test order with an email.  Look in the email for the exact template loaded.

Comment: thank you! :) but unfortunately, it didn't help much. We have  a fully functioning webshop (only moved from one www to another www). Because of this move, we have outdated contact information in transactional emails. So I thought making amends won't be that difficult, but I was wrong (:

Answer (score 0):

Check which template is really in use in your Magento shop (**remember about website/sotreview scope!**):

```
System > Configuration > Sales Emails > Order > New Order Confirmation Template
```

When set to different than default then check how looks overridden template:

```
System > Transactional Emails
```

And final: be sure that your store does not use 3rd party extension which manipulates of email templates.

Comment: Thank you, Marcin! In `System > Configuration > Sales Emails > Order > New Order Confirmation Template` I have only **Default Template from Locale** and in `System > Transactional Emails` there is nothing :)